# How should I log time when I fly from one airport to another and back again without landing?

Tags: logging

How should you log flight time when flying from airport A to airport B and return to airport A without landing at airport B?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Please tell us which country or regulations you're asking about: different countries have different rules.

Answer (score 2):

The time from when you started the engine to when you stopped the engine.  It doesn't matter where you went, except for where you specifically need to record the trip details for training requirements purposes, or for your own historical record.  So you'd log the overall trip time, startup to shutdown, adding something like, "CC YYY to XXX back to YYY - no landing at XXX" in the Remarks.

Comment: Just to clarify. Nothing goes in the cross-country column since there wasn’t a landing 50+ miles from where you started.

Comment: @JScarry I guess you're talking about FAA regulations? 61.1 has seven different definitions of cross-country time and not all of them require 50NM or a landing :-)

Comment: @Pondlife The question seems like it is coming from a student pilot, so that’s why I added the 50+ miles since thats what they need for FAA pilot certificates. Since there was no landing at all, it doesn’t count as cross country. Some military pilots can count flights without a landing as a cross country toward a rating, but I don’t believe anyone else can.

Comment: or as was done during my training, just log "XXXX local 1 hour" and never even mention where we went.